# Can you set SelectedItems on a DataGrid via a list

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have this code sitting in a button's attached TargetedTriggerAction<DataGrid>

What I'm trying to do is find the items that I'd like selected and place them into a list.
Once that is complete I'd like to set the DataGrid's SelectedItems with the list.

I would like to do it this way, as I have many thousands of items to iterate through, doing a majority on a background thread and setting SelectedItems at the end, avoiding the UI thread with singular calls to SelectedItems.Add() will be more efficient. That is my logic at this point anyway.

I realise that SelecteedItems is readonly so my question is can I actually do this? How can I set SelectedItems via a list? On another note if the SelectAll button can select everything in a short period of time then there must be a way achieve what I want also... shouldn't there?

```
IList<Object> tempItems = new List<Object>();
var itemsSource = this.Target.Items as IEnumerable;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.FullTextSearchInit();

    if (itemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            if (FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.Match((UserViewModel)item, sv))
            {
                tempItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (tempItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                /**** How to set? ****/
                this.Target.SelectedItems = tempList
                ));
        }
    }
});
```

**[EDIT]**
Tried doing the following, however, IsUpdatingSelectedItems, BeginUpdateSelectedItems and EndUpdateSelectedItems all come back with similar errors:

System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector.BeginUpdateSelectedItems()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
if (!this.Target.IsUpdatingSelectedItems)
{
    this.Target.BeginUpdateSelectedItems();
    foreach (object item in this.Target.Items)
    {
        if (FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.Match((UserViewModel)item, sv))
        {
            this.Target.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
    this.Target.EndUpdateSelectedItems();
}
```

Comment: You need to add the items individually to the *SelectedItems* list. However, you might want to use the DataGrid methods *BeginUpdateSelectedItems* and *EndUpdateSelectedItems* to suppress any superfluous and potentially slow GUI updates during this. Also, unrelated to your question, your code has a potential problem regarding *this.Target.Items* which is assigned to *itemsSource*: If duing the iteration of *this.Target.Items* in your task this collection is changed, the foreach loop might behave unpredictable or throw an exception...

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to know the way the Select All command works its magic? Does it populate SelectedItems individually? Also noted your warning, do you have an answer that could resolve this question?

Comment: It does it very similar. Look here at the [source code of the Selector class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Selector.cs#965f81a3c273e56e) from which DataGrid is derived. Specifically, look into the *SelectAllImpl()* method. Although it uses internal data structures, you will still find a *foreach* loop.

Comment: Ok good show. Still trying to piece this altogether. How do you get to the Selector of the DataGrid? And how do you ensure that if the collection changes that this does not break?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. *Selector* is a base class of DataGrid -- you can also say that DataGrid **is** a *Selector*. What you should do or not in your code regarding the items list depends very much on your code structure and i can thus give only a very broad advice here: First, determine if the potential problem is really a problem. If you found that there is indeed the possibility that the items list can change while the task is running you should guard any function that can modify the item list with some synchronization primitive (lock/Monitor/etc...). (contd...)

Comment: If you find that this would lead to too much safe-guarding with these synchronization primitives at too many places in your code, consider implementing your own List/Collection type for the items list, which should be capable to enable blocking of list modifications on demand (a-ka synchronization would happen inside that type only).

Comment: Hmm Autocomplete didn't come back with BeginUpdateSelectedItems and EndUpdateSelectedItems, I can see it in the MSDN class method definitions, manually typed it in. I added the results to the question above with the errors that it sent back.

Comment: @elgonzo how to implement BeginUpdateSelectedItems and EndUpdateSelectedItems. I have error posted in an [EDIT] above in the question

Comment: Note that the methods are **protected** (see their MSDN documentation). You have two choices: (A) Create your own MyDataGrid type inheriting from DataGrid, where you implement an *AddManyItemsToSelection* method which can call Begin/EndUpdateSelectedItems, or (B) you use reflection to invoke those protected methods from "outside" the DataGrid object instance.

Comment: I posted an answer specifically showing how you can use Begin/EndUpdateSelectedItems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments as well as in the edited question, it has been asked how to invoke the protected [BeginUpdateSelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.beginupdateselecteditems.aspx) and [EndUpdateSelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.endupdateselecteditems.aspx) methods of a DataGrid.

The simplest approach would be subclassing DataGrid and implement a method which can invoke those protected methods:

```
    public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public void SelectManyItems(IEnumerable itemsToBeSelected)
        {
            if (!IsUpdatingSelectedItems)
            {
                BeginUpdateSelectedItems();
                foreach (object item in itemsToBeSelected)
                    SelectedItems.Add(item);
                EndUpdateSelectedItems.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
```

While this looks nice and easy, it has the disadvantage of requiring you to replace the *DataGrid* with *MyDataGrid* wherever you need this functionality. When dealing with an existing or 3rd-party code base, this approach quickly becomes unfeasible.

Another, more versatile approach is in leveraging reflection to call the protected methods from "outside" of the DataGrid object instances. This does not require sub-classing of *DataGrid*.

```
public static class MultiSelectorHelper
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo _piIsUpdatingSelectedItems;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _miBeginUpdateSelectedItems;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _miEndUpdateSelectedItems;

    static MultiSelectorHelper()
    {
        _piIsUpdatingSelectedItems = typeof(MultiSelector).GetProperty("IsUpdatingSelectedItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        _miBeginUpdateSelectedItems = typeof(MultiSelector).GetMethod("BeginUpdateSelectedItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        _miEndUpdateSelectedItems = typeof(MultiSelector).GetMethod("EndUpdateSelectedItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }


    public static void SelectManyItems(this MultiSelector control, IEnumerable itemsToBeSelected)
    {
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (Action) (() =>
            {
                if (!(bool) _piIsUpdatingSelectedItems.GetValue(control, null))
                {
                    _miBeginUpdateSelectedItems.Invoke(control, null);
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (object item in itemsToBeSelected)
                            control.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _miEndUpdateSelectedItems.Invoke(control, null);
                    }
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Note that the *SelectManyItems* is implemented as an extension method, working on any control which is derived from *MultiSelector* (which includes DataGrid).

Also note the **try**-**finally** block, which ensures calling of the *EndUpdateSelectedItems* method even when an exception occurs during adding of the selected items.

Usage of this extension method is simple:

```
IEnumerable collectionWithItemsToSelect = ...
dataGridInstance.SelectManyItems(collectionWithItemsToSelect);
```

Comment: Oooh that was quick! Using the extension method, just tested on a 120000 records selecting 30000, took within a second. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `BeginUpdateSelectedItems` is such an important part of handling large data sets, it's ridiculous that it's protected, but subclassing is definitely the way to go. It's not as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Selecteditems in `SelectionChanged()`

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="ListViewSelectedItemsBinding.Window1"

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSelectedItemsBinding"

xmlns:w="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Workarounds"

x:Name="root" Width="500" Height="700">

<Window.Resources>

<local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>

<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended"

SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged"

w:ListView.HasBindableSelectedItems="True">

<ListView.View>

<GridView>

<GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Artist}" />

<GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}" />

<GridViewColumn Header="Genre" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Genre}" />

</GridView>

</ListView.View>

</ListView>

<StackPanel Background="LightGreen">

<DockPanel>

<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="SelectedItems.Count = " />

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItems.Count, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

</DockPanel>

<DockPanel>

<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="SelectedItems = " />

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay,

Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, ConverterParameter='Artist'}" IsReadOnly="True" />

</DockPanel>

</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Background="LightBlue">

<DockPanel>

<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Selection.Count = " />

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Selection.Count, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

</DockPanel>

<DockPanel>

<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Selection = " />

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Selection, Mode=OneWay,

Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, ConverterParameter='Artist'}" IsReadOnly="True" />

</DockPanel>

</StackPanel>

<local:PropertiesPanel x:Name="propertiesPanel1" Background="LightGreen"

Subjects="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}" />

<local:PropertiesPanel x:Name="propertiesPanel2" Background="LightBlue"

Subjects="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Selection, Mode=OneWay}" />

<local:PropertiesPanel x:Name="propertiesPanel3" Background="LightPink"

Subjects="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=BindableSelectedItems}" />

</StackPanel>

</Window>
```

background:

```
    using System;

using System.Collections;

using System.Windows.Data;

using System.Windows.Controls;



namespace System.Windows.Workarounds

{

public static class ListView

{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBindableSelectedItemsProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSelectedItemsProperty;

    static DependencyProperty SelectionChangedHandlerProperty;



    static ListView()

    {

    BindableSelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BindableSelectedItems", typeof(IList),typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListView));

    HasBindableSelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasBindableSelectedItems", typeof(bool),typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListView), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    SelectionChangedHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionChangedHandler", typeof(SelectionChangedHandler),typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListView));

    }



    public static void SetHasBindableSelectedItems(System.Windows.Controls.ListView source, bool value)
    {
    SelectionChangedHandler Handler = (SelectionChangedHandler)source.GetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);

    if (value && Handler == null)
    {
        Handler = new SelectionChangedHandler(source);
        source.SetValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty, Handler);
    } 
    else if (!value && Handler != null)
    {
        source.ClearValue(SelectionChangedHandlerProperty);
    }
}

}



internal class SelectionChangedHandler
{

    Binding Binding;
    internal SelectionChangedHandler(System.Windows.Controls.ListView owner)
    {
        Binding = new Binding("SelectedItems");
        Binding.Source = owner;
        owner.SetBinding(ListView.BindableSelectedItemsProperty, Binding);
        owner.SelectionChanged +=new SelectionChangedEventHandler(Owner_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void Owner_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.ListView Owner =(System.Windows.Controls.ListView)sender;
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(Owner, ListView.BindableSelectedItemsProperty);
        Owner.SetBinding(ListView.BindableSelectedItemsProperty, Binding);
    }
}
}
```

you can also make a dependencyproperty to replace 'selecteditems'

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html